# Extract elements from stdClass in PHP dynamically

Tags: php, laravel

I have stdClass returned from Laravel ORM result which looks like below,
[image]

I know I can access the value using $object->Tables_in_questip3_qgen, but "Tables_in_questip3_qgen" is dynamic. This can change to any string and I would like to extract values only from first element. I would like to have only adj_table,admin_fi and admin_fi_acount values across rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Laravel 5+ you can do this:

```
collect($object)->map(function ($v) {
     return head((array)$v);
});
```

To get a subarray of arbitrary items (by the order they appear):

```
$indices = [ 0, 1 ];
collect($object)->map(function ($v) use ($indices) {
     $inner = collect($v)->values();
     return $inner->only($indices); //This will return the requested indices as a collection, but you can realistically do whatever you want with them like e.g. ->implode or ->toArray
});
```

Comment: Thanks, works like charm.. where can i find documentation on such methods.

Comment: @anandatheerthan collections had been added in Laravel since 5.0 but the methods were not documented until 5.1 apparently. Check out https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections . `head` is documented in the [helper methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#available-methods) section

Comment: according to the documentation, head function "The head function simply returns the first element in the given array:". I don't get the point as to how it returns values of all keys in the array.

Comment: also, how do i get the output with value of second key as well.for ex, adj_table,BASE TABLE.

Comment: @anandatheerthan check the update on how to get a subarray based on required indices.